# Integral of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\sin(ax)-1)^ne^{-\frac{x^2}{4b}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I would like to evaluate the following integral

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\sin(ax)-1)^ne^{-\frac{x^2}{4b}}dx$.

Is there an analytical expression for this integral (maybe in terms of special functions)? I suppose that there probably is no general expression for arbitrary $n$. Are there any approximations to be made, that are valid for large $a$, $b$ and $n$? I already tried expanding $(\sin(ax)-1)^n$ as a Taylor series around $0$ up to second order but as expected this is not a good approximation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral can be expressed as a summation of an analytical series. I hope it come out handy enough to work with.

First,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\sin(ax)-1)^ne^{-\frac{x^2}{4b}}dx
{=
2\sqrt{b}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\sin(2a\sqrt{b}x)-1)^ne^{-x^2}dx
\\=
2\sqrt{b}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[\frac{e^{i2a\sqrt{b}x}-e^{-i2a\sqrt{b}x}-2i}{2i}\right]^ne^{-x^2}dx
\\=
\frac{2\sqrt{b}}{(2i)^n}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[{e^{ia\sqrt{b}x}-ie^{-ia\sqrt{b}x}}\right]^{2n}e^{-x^2}dx
\\=
\frac{2\sqrt{b}}{(2i)^n}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}{e^{i2a\sqrt{b}x(k-n)}}(-i)^{2n-k}e^{-x^2}dx
\\=
\frac{2\sqrt{b}}{(2i)^n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}(-i)^{2n-k}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{i2a\sqrt{b}x(k-n)}}e^{-x^2}dx
}.
$$
Second, by using the Fourier transform, we achieve
$$
\sqrt{\pi}\exp(-k^2)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-x^2)\exp(-i2kx)dx.
$$
Finally,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\sin(ax)-1)^ne^{-\frac{x^2}{4b}}dx{=
2\sqrt{b\pi}\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}i^{k} e^{-a^2b(k-n)^2}
}
.
$$

**Update**

A simpler series is as follows:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\sin(ax)-1)^ne^{-\frac{x^2}{4b}}dx{=
2\sqrt{b\pi}\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}i^{k} e^{-a^2b(k-n)^2}
\\=
2\sqrt{b\pi}\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^n\Big[
\binom{2n}{n}i^{n}
+
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\Bigg\{\binom{2n}{k}i^{k} e^{-a^2b(k-n)^2}
\\+
\binom{2n}{2n-k}i^{2n-k} e^{-a^2b(2n-k-n)^2}\Bigg\}\Big]
\\=
2\sqrt{b\pi}\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^n\Big[
\binom{2n}{n}i^{n}
+
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}\left(i^{k}+i^{2n-k}\right) e^{-a^2b(k-n)^2}
\Big]
\\=
\binom{2n}{n}2\sqrt{b\pi}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n
+
2\sqrt{b\pi}\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^n
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}\left(i^{k}+i^{2n-k}\right) e^{-a^2b(k-n)^2}
\\=
\binom{2n}{n}2\sqrt{b\pi}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n
+
2\sqrt{b\pi}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}\left(i^{-k}+i^{k}\right) e^{-a^2bk^2}
\\=
2\sqrt{b\pi}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\cdot\left[
\binom{2n}{n}
+
2
\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{2n}{n-2k}(-1)^k e^{-4a^2bk^2}
\right]
}
.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$I_n=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(\sin(ax)-1)^n\,e^{-\frac{x^2}{4b}}\,dx$$

Let $x=\frac t a$ and $k=\frac{1}{4 a^2 b}$ and rewrite
$$I_n=\frac 1 a\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (-1)^n (1-\sin(t))^n\,e^{-k t^2}\,dt$$  Using the binomial expansion, you face integrals looking like
$$J_{m}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \sin^{2m}(t)\,e^{-k t^2}\,dt$$
Using
$$\sin^{2m}(t)=\frac 1{2^{2m} }\Bigg[\sum _{k=0}^{m-1} \left(2 (-1)^{m-k} \binom{2 m}{k} \cos (2
   (m-k)t)+\binom{2 m}{m}\right)\Bigg]$$
and
$$K_{n}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \cos(2n t)\,e^{-k t^2}\,dt=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{k}}\,\,\exp\left(-\frac{n^2}k \right)$$